# Json not returning after ajax call

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, mysqli

### HTML PAGE

```
$("#submit_login").click(function() {
    var username = $('input[name=user_email]').val();
    var password = $('input[name=user_password]').val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "newExam.php",
        data: {
            name: username,
            pwd: password
        },
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#submit_login").val('Connecting...');
        },
        success: function(dataa) {
            if (dataa) {
                alert(dataa);
                $("#submit_login").val('success')
            } else {
                $("#submit_login").val('Login')
                alert('nodata')
            }
        }
    });
});
```

### PHP PAGE

```
 <?php  
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "12345";
$dbname = "uvm_server";
// Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }  
  $email_php = $_POST['name'];  
  $pwd_php=$_POST['pwd'];
  echo $email_php;
 echo $pwd_php;
    $sql = "select name from user where email='$email_php'";  
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);  
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
   {  
   echo "<p>".$row['name']."</p>";  
   $rows[]=$row;
   } 
   echo '{"members":'.json_encode($rows).'}';
   ?>
```

When i look into resources i am able to get the output. But The success function is not getting trigerred.  I need the output of the SQL query as JSON which can be accessed in javascript. so that i can validate the usser name and password.
It always shows Connecting...  I want to know if my ajax call is correct or not

Comment: Seems that your output is not contain only JSON, hence jQuery failed to parse.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to make it as json?

Comment: FIrst, you are using the old syntax of ajax with `success`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `<p>` output, that's not JSON.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{  
    $rows[]=$row;
} 
echo json_encode(array('members' => $rows));
```